# java not found error when running docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have simple Dockerfile as below :

```
FROM centos:centos7

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jre8u352-b05-ea-ubuntu-nightly

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /home/centos

COPY ./abc.jar /tmp/abc.jar

CMD ["java" "-jar", "/tmp/abc.jar"]
```

Now, after building the image , trying to run the container using `docker run` command , but it is giving error

> /bin/sh: 1: [java: not found

I simply don't understand what's the issue here. I'm assuming that ,  openjdk image will create the java environment and set all PATHS .

Please suggest

Comment: please suggest . kind of blocked

Comment: You are missing a comma `,` between `"java"` and `"-jar"`.

Comment: you don't need `FROM centos:centos7`, I will use `WORKDIR /data`, `COPY ./abc.jar /data/app.jar`, `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/data/app.jar"]`

Comment: OK thanks , got it. I don't understand why I should not use FROM centos:centos7. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Why two or more FROM in a Dockerfile ? use 1 `FROM` as base image is enough. Or you want to try `Multi-stage builds` https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/ , It will have multi `FROM` in a Dockerfile.

Comment: I will use `eclipse-temurin:8u352-b08-jre-alpine` , it only 139MB,  Use `docker images | grep adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jre8u352-b05-ea-ubuntu-nightly`  is 224MB,

Comment: My native language is not English, so my answer will be short, I hope you can understand.